# Capture mouse left click

Tags: powershell

I need to count the total number clicks made by a user in a day.
I want to use powershell for this as it should be simplest but i am not able to find any simple method in it to capture the mouse event.

Can somebody guide me on this [Using windows 7]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This utility works on my win7 machine:

http://www.jholu.com/2012/04/21/mouse-click-counter-for-windows-to-count-left-right-and-middle-clicks/

You can also try this .NET project if you need to automate it:

http://globalmousekeyhook.codeplex.com